# Issues Building ROS2: Dashing Python Package

Tags: ros2, python3, create, rclpy, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've tried following this tutorial page (https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Tutorials/Colcon-Tutorial/) to build my own python package for ROS2 Dashing on Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic), but I'm running into issues.

Here is a link to my package:  https://github.com/SouLeo/ROS2_AllenNLP_Parser/tree/master/parser
It includes my setup.cfg, setup.py, and package.xml.

My issue is that, even though I can build successfully with

```
colcon build --symlink-install
```

after sourcing with

```
source ~/ws/install/setup.bash
```

I can't run

```
ros2 run temoto_parser srl_test
```

Instead I get an error:

```
Package 'temoto_parser' not found
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332452/issues-building-ros2:-dashing-python-package/) by [SouLeo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35604/souleo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2019-09-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think `ros2 run` uses the ament index to find packages, and it looks like the package `temoto_parser` isn't installing a marker file.

Create a folder called `resource/` (this folder name doesn't really matter, it's just what's been used so far) in the same directory as your `setup.py` file. Next, create an empty file with the same name as your package in that folder: `resource/temoto_parser`. In your `setup.py` use the `data_files` keyword argument to install the marker file `temoto_parser` to `share/ament_index/resource_index/packages`.

See the [ros2/examples repo](https://github.com/ros2/examples) for python packages that do this. [Here's the relevant part of the setup.py](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/898a753e8c6e8c6ba14cbf5eb3264113cf3b2bc7/rclpy/topics/minimal_publisher/setup.py#L9-L11), and [here's a marker file in a folder called `resource`](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/master/rclpy/topics/minimal_publisher/resource).

Here's [a page with a little more info about the ament_index](https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Tutorials/Ament-CMake-Documentation/#the-ament-index-explained), though it's targeted at packages using CMake.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SouLeo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35604/souleo/) on 2019-09-06**:
Thank you so much! This solved my problem!

**Comment by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on 2019-09-07**:
I believe this is due to a bug in colcon core. Package discovery currently uses *either* setup.py *or* setup.cfg. I’m working on a fix in https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/pull/215

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-09-07**:
This behavior is not a bug. Earlier `colcon-ros` did this automatically for the user but that "magic" has recently been removed (https://github.com/colcon/colcon-ros/pull/74) since it makes it difficult for users to spot that while it works when building from source it would fall when packaging the package into e.g a Debian package.

**Comment by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) on 2019-09-07**:
I think there is a bug here, though I may have misattributed it. Here's which files change when you remove the **setup.cfg** and `colcon build --symlink-install`. Note the `path.*` hooks so that, without **setup.cfg**, the directory containing `srl_test` gets injected into `PATH`:

```
-./build/temoto_parser/setup.cfg
-./install/temoto_parser/lib/temoto_parser
-./install/temoto_parser/lib/temoto_parser/srl_test
-./src/ROS2_AllenNLP_Parser/parser/setup.cfg

+./install/temoto_parser/bin
+./install/temoto_parser/bin/srl_test
+./install/temoto_parser/share/temoto_parser/hook/path.dsv
+./install/temoto_parser/share/temoto_parser/hook/path.ps1
+./install/temoto_parser/share/temoto_parser/hook/path.py
+./install/temoto_parser/share/temoto_parser/hook/path.sh
```